# How can I search only title of Textbook model using elasticsearch Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch

EDIT1:
How can I do any Textbook :title has "java"? It only match a textbook exactly "java". If a book title is "java2" or "java-algo" it won't show.. Thanks in advance!

Hi I installed elasticsearch and it is working.
I have Textbook model:

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Textbook < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    belongs_to :user


    #below is for sunspot
    #searchable do
        #text :title, :default_boost => 2
        #text :subject
    #end

    #include ActiveModel::Validations
    validates :title, :presence => true
    validates :subject, :presence => true
    validates :price, :presence => true
    validates :offer, :presence => false
    validates :user_email, :presence => true
    validates :description, :presence => true
end

Textbook.import
```

But When I search for like for example "java"
Not only title of book "java" but also all attributes has "java" shows..
I want to see only the search result a book which title is "java"

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

    def search
      if params[:search].nil?
        #@textbooks = []
        @textbooks = Textbook.all.order(created_at: :desc)
      else
        @textbooks = Textbook.search params[:search]
      end
    end
end
```

Below is search form inside of views/textbooks/index.html.erb

```
<div>
          <%= form_tag search_path, :method => :get do %>
            <p>
              <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search textbooks" %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", :title => nil, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
```

## Update!#!#!#!#!#!#!

When I try do your advice like below:

```
@textbooks = Textbook.search index: 'INDEXNAME', body: {query: { constant_score: { filter: {term: { title: params[:search]} } }}}
```

I get eeror:

```
[400] {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. unknown search element [index]","line":1,"col":2}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"textbooks","node":"RPfuoi8FQLWkC8OIj5uUNQ","reason":{"type":"search_parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. unknown search element [index]","line":1,"col":2}}]},"status":400}
Extracted source (around line #18):

          <tbody>
            <% @textbooks.each do |textbook| %>
              <tr>
                <!--<td><%= textbook.title %></td>-->
                <td><%=link_to "#{textbook.title}", textbook_path(textbook.id) %></td>
```

My goal is to find any match `:title` and `:subject` attributes from model name `Textbook`

Comment: read this, it may helpful to you  . https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it this way

```
Textbook.search index: 'INDEXNAME', body: { query: { match: { title: params[:search] } } }
```

Syntax:

```
    Textbook.search index: 'INDEXNAME', body: { query: { match: { COLUMN_NAME: STRING } } }
```

For non-complex and simpler usage:
you can try [searchkick gem](http://searchkick.org/)

Its Simple and straight forword to use. Its basically built on top of elasticsearch gem.

Comment: Thank you very much!. How can I do any Textbook :title has "java"?
Your suggest only match exactly "java". If a book title is "java2" it won't show.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Textbook.search index: 'INDEXNAME', body: {query: { constant_score: { filter: {term: { COLUMN_NAME: STRING} } }}}

Comment: Why am I getting `Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::BadRequest in Search#search_textbook` error...